# Vector Iterator (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've designed a program to read in data from a CSV file containing information from a live updating meteorological centre.

I am now in the process of splitting up certain duties into functions, I'm required to print the average windspeed & radiation for each month of a specified year.
The sample input:
{Year}
2016

Sample output:
{Month, Avg Windspeed, Avg Radiation}
January, 5.5, 196.4
February, 4.4, 200.3
...
etc.

My program is setup as a vector of "WindData", which contains different classes such as 'Date', 'Time' & windspeed data.

This following function is the one i'm having issues with:

```
void averageWind(int yearNum, std::vector<WindData>& windlog)
{
    std::string month[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                            "July", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int monthCount = 0, monthNum[12] = {0}, monthAverage[12] = {0};
    int dayCount[12] = {0}, totalWindSpeed[12] = {0}, totalRadiation[12] = {0}, mWindAverage[12] = {0};

    std::vector<WindData>::iterator iter;
    for(iter = windlog.begin(); iter != windlog.end(); iter++)
    {
        if(iter->getYear() == yearNum)
        {
            for(int i = 0;  i < 12; i++)
            {
                while((iter->getMonth()-1) == i)
                {
                    dayCount[i]++;
                    totalWindSpeed[i] += iter->getSpeed();
                }
                std::cout << "Wind Speed: " << totalWindSpeed[i] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Day Count: " << dayCount[i] << std::endl;
                mWindAverage[i] = (totalWindSpeed[i] / dayCount[i]);

                //std::cout << mWindAverage[i];
                //std::cout << month[i];
            }

        }


    }


}
```

This is obviously not complete and the print methods are there just for testing purposes, my issue is that totalWindSpeed and dayCount are both producing 0.
I've attempted to debug the code to determine where it is going wrong and it seems that there is a problem with the iterator itself, however this worked previously when i had it within my main function.

The error is as follows:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

What could be causing this? I've read up about deferencing the iterator etc. but from what I can tell it's setup right.

Comment: can you provide the code that calls this function? also you should run in a debugger and find where the segfault occurs

Comment: Use a debugger to find the exact point where program segfaults

Comment: `while((iter->getMonth()-1) == i)` looks very dangerous to me. If neither `iter` nor `i` is incremented in the loop, your program may never break out of the loop.

Comment: Agree with @DafangCao. If the while condition is true, neither `i` nor `iter` is getting changed inside loop.

Comment: Here is the full code in main:
http://pastebin.com/cHaM6NMG

The debugger is telling me that the segfault occurs at line 106,107,108 which is the lines starting under string month[12] declaration.
Very confusing.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I've tried that to no avail, same problem.

Comment: You only have 11 months, you're missing August :D . But after you fix this, you still need to fix what @DafangCao mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, missed that one!

@DafangCao Right you are! Would you have any other workaround to iterate through each day of each month of the specified year, grabbing the windspeeds and radiation levels?

Too much coding today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information I would do something like this.

```
for (WindData& windData : windlog) {
    if (windData.getYear() == yearNum) {
        int i = windData.getMonth() - 1;
        totalWindSpeed[i] += windData.getSpeed();
        dayCount[i]++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // If each month appears only once, this may go into the previous loop.
    mWindAverate[i] = totalWindSpeed[i] / dayCount[i];
}
```

Comment: I get the following error:
error: expected unqualified-id before ':' token|

Relating to line 
for(auto WindData : winlog)

I've never used auto before so i'm not sure of how it works.

Comment: @MichaelBell Edited: `auto` in this case is the type `WindData&`. If your compiler is pre-C++11, it may support neither `auto` nor enhanced `for` loop. If that is the case, your solution already has the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks! 
Your code seems to be working, could you give me some insight as to why my algorithm was giving me such an error?

Comment: @MichaelBell Sorry for the late reply. The `while` loop in your original code may cause an integer overflow, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Integer division by zero is also undefined behavior AFAIK (Nice catch Cristi!). Therefore I cannot say for sure why you are getting a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is here:

```
mWindAverage[i] = (totalWindSpeed[i] / dayCount[i]);
```

For the most values of i dayCount[i] ist zero. I expect your segmentation fault comes from here. You should test first the value to divide with is not zero.

The second problem is this

```
for(int i = 0;  i < 12; i++)
```

You do not have to iterate through the months again. You only have to add to the right month when you read the data with the iterator. See the other answer above (does not test for division with 0 either !!). Your code becomes suddelny needless complicated.